# How to copy a file into another file but replace a word with a user entered word?

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy a file to another file, but change a word with what the user has entered. So far I have come up with this:

```
while (getline(openningTheFile, line, ' ')) //line is a string and openningTheFile is an ifstream 
{
    if (line == wordToBeDeleted)
    {
        line = wordToReplaceWith;

    }
    if (line == "\n")
    {
        newFile << endl; //newFile is an ofstream 
    }

    newFile << line << " ";
}
```

But the problem is that this code does not read the word after the `"\n"` because the delimiter is spaces.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strategy I recommend:

1. Read the file line by line using `std::getline`.
2. Look for the string that you would like to replace in the line using `std::string::find`.
3. If it is found, replace it with the new string.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the string is not found.
5. Output the updated line.

Here's the core code for that:

```
while (getline(openningTheFile, line)) 
{ 
   std::string::size_type pos;
   while ( (pos = line.find(wordToBeDeleted)) != std::string::npos )
   {
      line.replace(pos, wordToBeDeleted.length(), wordToReplaceWith);
   }
   newFile << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Best answer so far, because that method preserves all whitespaces.

Comment: You can't put declarations inside expressions.

Comment: It doesn't handle compound words though. If the user wants to replace the word "fire" for example, your algorithm would also replace part of the word "firefly".

Comment: @zett42, true. Hopefully the OP will be able to adapt their code to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a *line* of text with `std::getline`.

You will need to find the word within the text line, replace the word, then write the text line to the output file.

One method is to use `std::stringstream` and operator `>>` to extract the word from the string.

Another is to use `std::string::find` to locate the position of the word.

Comment: is it possible for you to expand on how to use stringstream to extract the word from the string and have it replaced?

Comment: @mohsen That's answered in my post. Do you need to preserve the whitespaces also?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i need the new file created to be exactly the word that was changed

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying the loop to read word-wise from the line read using `std::istringstream`:

```
while (getline(openningTheFile, line)) 
{ 
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string word;
    bool firstWord = true;
    while(iss >> word)
    {
        if(word == wordToBeDeleted) {  
            newFile << wordToReplaceWith;
            if(!firstWord) {
                newFile << " ";
            }
            firstWord = false;
        }
    }
    newFile << `\n`;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this delete all whitespace between the words in the output?

Comment: @zett42 Oops, yes.

Comment: Now you are collapsing adjacent ws in input to single ws in output. Pretty destructive still ;-)

Comment: @zett42 Fixed. Doesn't preserve any additional whitespaces though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the power of [boost::iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/) to solve the task in a high level but still very flexible way.

For OP's case this is propably like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut, but if one needs flexibility or has to deal with more complex cases, it might be the right tool.

I'm using a [filtering stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/filter_usage.html) combined with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This allows us to replace a search pattern with a substitution string on-the-fly, without creating any intermediate string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    // Your input "file" - you may replace it by an std::ifstream object.
    istringstream in( "why waste time learning learninglearning, when ignorance is instantaneous?" );

    // Search pattern and substitution string.        
    string findRegEx( R"(\blearning\b)" );
    string replaceStr( "sleeping" );

    // Build a regular expression filter and attach it to the input stream.
    io::filtering_istream inFiltered;
    inFiltered.push( io::regex_filter( boost::regex( findRegEx ), replaceStr ) );
    inFiltered.push( in );

    // Copy the filtered input to the output, replacing the search word on-the-fly.
    // Replace "cout" by your output file, e. g. an std::ofstream object.
    io::copy( inFiltered, cout );

    cout << endl;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6ETB9V8fnEKGmt1C)**

**Output:**

```
why waste time sleeping learninglearning, when ignorance is instantaneous?
```

**Notes:**

- The actual regular expression is `\blearning\b`
- We don't need to escape the backslash because we are using a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Very neat for stuff like this.
- The regular expression searches for the whole word "learning" (`\b` denotes a word boundary).  That's why it only replaces the first occurence of "learning" and not "learninglearning".